# eslint plugin fp, jest and react testing library causes unwanted linting errors

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, jestjs, eslint, react-testing-library

I installed the plugin [`eslint-plugin-fp`](https://github.com/jfmengels/eslint-plugin-fp) to help me write better code. I'm writing a React app. I do TDD writing my tests with Jest and react-testing-library.

The problem that I have is that the plugin throws a lot of errors in the test files because `describe` doesn't return anything.

[image]

How can you use that plugin in conjunction with tests?

Comment: You probably want to follow/comment on this issue in the eslint-plugin-fp repo: https://github.com/jfmengels/eslint-plugin-fp/issues/25

Comment: @JordanRunning didn't see that issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a great solution, but personally I would put an `.eslintrc.json` file in the test directory or directories that overrides the parent configuration to disable those rules, e.g.:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "fp/no-nil": "off",
    "fp/no-unused-expression": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. Tests follow different rules from normal code. It makes sense to disable these lint checks for them.

Comment: Yeah. I wish you could define eslintignores for specific rules Thanks, thought.